# make a placeholder visible on a value of a bind textbox from a database in a formview

Tags: asp.net

I have a sqldatasourece control and formview control inside the the formview i have a place holder that is not visible. I would like to make the place holder visible if a textbox (inside the the same formview) has a value of "yes".

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="Load_SystemsTextBox" runat="server" 
                             Text='<%# Bind("Load_Systems") %>' />


    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderItem3Yes" runat="server" Visible="False">
the value returned from the database equals yes
                         </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I'm trying to make the placeholder visible in the cobe behind but the following dosent work

```
  PlaceHolder PlaceHolderItem3Yes = (PlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderItem3Yes");    
            TextBox Load_SystemsTextBox = (TextBox)FormView2.FindControl("Load_SystemsTextBox");


            if (Load_SystemsTextBox.Text == "YES")
            {
                PlaceHolderItem2Yes.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                PlaceHolderItem2Yes.Visible = false;
            }
```

Comment: There are a few things we need to know: 1) is the control being found? 2) where is this code being called? 3) is there any code that gets executed after which changes the visibility?

Comment: 1)I'm not get an error in the codebehind so i would say the control is  being found 2) I ahve tried calling it in the page_load and the Fronview_itemCreated 3) No

Comment: I just noticed that in your code example, the master page control you're finding is `PlaceHolderItem3Yes` whereas in your if/else logic you're toggling the visibility of `PlaceHolderItem2Yes`. Possibly an oversight in your code?

Comment: I wish i have three place holder on the page and neither of them are visible sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can not see a PlaceHolder. 
**The control renders only its child elements; it renders no markup of its own.** Read more here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z05bh12b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Should I put it in a comment rather than an answer?